# Track FPS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, frame-rate

Basicly I'm doing some animations with jQuery and for debugging purposes, I'd love to see how many frames per second are my animations running in.

Are there any scripts out there that do such a thing, or a simple solution? And if not, then how could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about my suggestion? I don't have anything here to test it in, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this question: https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js

Mr. Doob has a great little plugin for working out framerate

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a global variable that gets increased by one every time a frame is rendered, then with the use of `setInterval` set this value back to 0 and output the value.

```
var frames = 0;

function render_frame(){

    /* With this function I mean the place where you render a frame */
    frames++;    

}

setInterval(function() {

    $('#fps').html(frames+' fps');
    frames = 0;

}, 1000);
```

This way you start with a framerate of 0, and for one second the amount of frames are counted, then at the end of the second the framecount is reset and outputted, resulting in FPS.

Comment: The problem here is that I cannot track "each" frame separately, when animating with `animate()`... Or maybe I just haven't found a way to do it. Plus the other thing is, that there are multiple elements being animated at the same time, that affects actual FPS.